# Method defined in derived class and only declare in base class. Undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is it possible to just declare a in base class and leave the implementation in derived class?

I thought that is possible, but the following doesn't work.

```
#include <vector>
template <typename I>
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    template <typename T2, typename A2>
    void test0(const std::vector<T2,A2>& vec,const I n) {
        test(vec[0]);
    }
private:
    template <typename I2> void test(const I2 a);
};

template <typename I>
class B: public A<I> {
public:
    B() {}
private:
    template <typename I2> void test(const I2 n) {}
};

int main() {
    B<int> b;
    std::vector<int> x(100);
    b.test0(x,0);
}
```

Linker error:

```
/tmp/test7-76b4cc.o: In function `void A<int>::test0<int, std::allocator<int> >(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, int)':
test7.cpp:(.text._ZN1AIiE5test0IiSaIiEEEvRKSt6vectorIT_T0_Ei[_ZN1AIiE5test0IiSaIiEEEvRKSt6vectorIT_T0_Ei]+0x35): undefined reference to `void A<int>::test<int>(int)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: In your case the method in the base class and the derived class are not the same method because they are not `virtual`.

Comment: Also, templates don't work the way you think they do.

Comment: even constructor can take extra template parameter that is not defined for the whole class. i got that by testing g++ and clang++.  virtual hurts performance if that thing get called many times (or I thought so).

Comment: @r.xu Tell me what `virtual` does

Comment: In your case (confusingly) `a` is always of type `B`, so there would be no virtual calls anyway.

Comment: @BoPersson The question isn't asking whether there would or would not be a virtual call.

Comment: i am going to ask a new question about virtual call/dynamic dispatch. just to make sure. compilers just say templates can't be virtual

Comment: @immibis - The OP is trying to avoid a supposedly expensive virtual call. And he already did that by not using runtime polymorphism. So, problem solved?

Comment: That's correct. Templates can't be virtual because templates don't work the way they think you do.

Comment: And if you think about it, "only virtual functions can be overridden" and "templates can't be virtual" implies that you can't override templates. Which is true.